# VaR and Expected Shorfall estimations with negative shape parameter of a GPD (Extreme Value Theory )

Tags: risk, value-at-risk, expected-shortfall, pareto-distribution

So im trying to replicate an code from the Quantative Risk Management Book (https://github.com/qrmtutorial/qrm/blob/master/code/09_Market_Risk/09_Standard_methods_for_market_risk.R). But when i try a rolling window estimation -last 1000 observations- using the 'POT' method in my data ( log loss of "PETR4.SA" , Petrobras ticker in BOVESPA , from 2006 to end of 2020 ), i got an error ( around "2006-01-16/ + 1000 days" ) message telling that the Risk measure is not implemented for negative shape parameter of the GPD. I've read the book (QRM) and other papers about GPD for tail estimation but i could not find any reference to the restriction in the shape must being positive. The code for the VaR and ES estimation are below:

VaR_95 <- u + (beta/shape)*(((1-alpha_95)/length(excess) / length(Losses))^(-shape)-1)
ES_95 <- (VaR_95 + beta-shape*u) / (1-xi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's me again...
So i find out what a negative shape parameter in Generalized Pareto Distribuition means and why it's not possible to calculate EVT with it. negative shape parameter means that the distribuition has a limit, not quite what you are looking for when fitting an **extreme** value theory model.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to us. This information may be helpful to others in the future.